# Google maps api v3 : How can I calculate bounds of map 1cm short from all sides?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to avoid showing markers which are at **map edges** because their **infowindow** is half visible(and I dont want to drag the map while showing infowindow). For this how can I calculate map bounds little bit smaller than the original bounds(for e.g **1cm** or **40px** from all sides).

Or is there any better solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a padding around the edge of a google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712268/how-to-create-a-padding-around-the-edge-of-a-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

I got it...
Here is the code:

```
function setRectangle(center){
     var scale = Math.pow(2,MainMap.getZoom());
     var proj = MainMap.getProjection();
     var wc = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(center);
     var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var sw = new google.maps.Point(((wc.x * scale) - (($('#google-map-canvas').width() - 75)*0.5))/ scale, ((wc.y * scale) - (($('#google-map-canvas').height() - 75)*0.5))/ scale);
bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(sw));
var ne = new google.maps.Point(((wc.x * scale) + (($('#google-map-canvas').width() - 75)*0.5))/ scale, ((wc.y * scale) + (($('#google-map-canvas').height() - 75)*0.5))/ scale);
bounds.extend(proj.fromPointToLatLng(ne));
     var opts = {
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0,
        bounds: bounds,
        map: MainMap
     };
enclosedRectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle(opts);
}
```